# How do I edit this element in TYPO3?

Tags: cms, typo3

Hopefully I am posting this on the right site.  I am trying to take over maintenance of a web site.  The developer used Typo3 for a CMS.  The problem is that I am not that familiar with Typo3 and I can't seem to find any reference to this in the documentation.  All I am trying to do is edit the text of an element on the main page (which I believe is part of a template).  I have a flash video of the screen and the actions I think I need to perform in order to get the text edited.  I am trying to change the element named "Showcase" that reads "Advertisement" and has text reading "Free shipping for $99+ orders online".  I'd like to change that text and I can't seem to figure out how to edit it.  Take a look at my screen capture video and let me know what I am doing wrong.  The link is:  [Typo3 Screen Capture](http://db.tt/nfMrkv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have no rights to edit the templates or the templates aren't there